# Findstr: Regex with Variable

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file and it is formated like this;

```
(1992){0103644}[00004]
(1999){0137523}[00019]
(1991){0103064}[00098]
(2001){0246578}[00103]
(2011){1399103}[00150]
```

What i am trying to do finding a variable (which is entered by user) inside this text. Variable had to be search between `{}` This is what i am trying;

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SIRA=1"
set "TEST=103"
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=(){}[]" %%a in ('findstr /irc:"\{[0-9]*!TEST![0-9]*\}" %MURL%') do (
  set FISIM[!SIRA!]=%%a
  set FYIL[!SIRA!]=%%b
  set FIDD[!SIRA!]=%%c
  set /a SIRA+=1
)
set /a SIRA-=1
for /l %%i in (1,1,!SIRA!) do call :_Yazdir "%%i" "!FISIM[%%i]!" "!FYIL[%%i]!" "!FIDD[%%i]!" "!SATIRRENGI!"
goto :EOF
```

it works ONLY if i write the variable inside the findstr (in this case its `!TEST!` replaced by `103`). So is there a possible way to find it ?

**PS:** %MURL% contains the name of text file.

**PS:** :_Yazdir is the function that i use for print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tap into a regex engine that supports lookarounds, you can use this regex:

```
(?<={)[^}]+(?=})
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/tA7wA0)

For instance, with `grep` in Perl mode, you can do:

```
grep -P "(?<={)[^}]+(?=})" myfile
```

In the comments you say you are on Windows, so you can use `pcregrep` (which is part of the `PCRE` distribution).

**Explanation**

- The `(?<={)` lookbehind asserts that what precedes is a `{`
- `[^}]+` matches one or more chars that are not a `}`
- The `(?=})` lookahead asserts that what follows is a `}`

**Reference**

- [Grep in PCRE](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html)
- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: well i am using win8 and i cant install anything :(

Comment: On Win8 you have `pcregrep`, which you don't need to install. You can get a binary from [this page](http://www.rexegg.com/pcregrep-pcretest.html). There may be other tools, I'm not too familiar with the shell, but `pcregrep` works.

Comment: Your way is prety good. But i have to try with limited regex from findstr :(. Using tools which is not directly came from win8 forbidden.

Comment: In PowerShell you can do `$string -match` and use the regex I gave you, i.e. something like `$string -match '(?<={)[^}]+(?=})'` Basically this is the right regex, your job is to find the tool that will work with it in your environment. If powershess doesn't work google something like Windows batch lookahead :)

Answer (score 1):

I found why my code doesnt work. I was using a variable name which is like `XXX[1]`. So when findstr started regex search it was assuming `[1]` had to be on the text file.. Silly me i wasted hours to see this mistake :(

Comment: You might like to consider deleting your question if you have the rights to do so, as your code was working.